# Probability of stock price modeled by brownian motion with drift

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Given a stock price modeled by Brownian motion with drift with $u=1$ and $\sigma=1.5$. Assume the stock price is $40$ at $t=0$ and $60$ at $t=10$, find the probability that the stock price is between $40$ and $60$ at $t=5$?

**My attempt:** I computed $P(X(5)>40\ |\ X(0)=40) = 1 - \phi(\frac{-5}{\sqrt{11.25}})$ and $P(X(5)>60\ |\ X(0)=40) =  1 - \phi(\frac{15}{\sqrt{11.25}})$, so $P(X(5)\in (40,60)\ |\ X(0) = 40) = \phi(\frac{15}{\sqrt{11.25}}) - \phi(\frac{-5}{\sqrt{11.25}})$.

Now, using Brownian bridge, I also could compute $P(X(5)> 60\ |\ X(10)=60) = 1-\phi(\frac{59}{3\sqrt{2.5}})$, as well as $P(X(5)>40\ |\ X(10) = 60) = 1-\phi(\frac{19}{3\sqrt{2.5}})$, thus $P(X(5)\in (40,60)\ |\ X(10) = 60) = \phi(\frac{59}{3\sqrt{2.5}}) - \phi(\frac{19}{3\sqrt{2.5}})$.

Finally, since $X(10)$ and $X(0)$ are independent, $P(X(5)\in (40, 60)\ |\ X(0)=40, X(10) = 60) = P(X(5)\in (40, 60)\ |\ X(0)=40)\ P(X(5)\in (40, 60)\ |\ X(10)=60) = [\phi(\frac{59}{3\sqrt{2.5}}) - \phi(\frac{19}{3\sqrt{2.5}})][\phi(\frac{15}{\sqrt{11.25}}) - \phi(\frac{-5}{\sqrt{11.25}})]$

**My question:** Is the last step in my solution correct? On the other hand, I could not really combine the two given informations at $t=0$ and $t=10$, as we actually only need $1$ of them to figure out the required probability. I am confused why we need two given information rather than one. Could anyone please help explain the reason? Any thoughts on the solution above would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Could anyone give me some feedbacks on my solution? I'm thinking of another way to solve it, which is to let $Y(t)=X(t)-40$, then $Y(t)$ is also a Brownian process following $N(t-40, 1.5^{2}t)$. Then I need to compute $P(0<Y(5)<20)$, which is easy as $Y(5)\equiv N(-35, 1.5^2)$. Is this new solution better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let study $X_5$ and $X_{10}$. We have a condition on $X_0$(backward) and $X_{10}(forward)$.

We have that $X_t=X_0+ut+\sigma W_t$, and therefore

$E(X_5)=45$

$E(X_{10})=50$

$var(X_5)=\sigma^25$

$var(X_{10})=\sigma^210$ 
and finally $cov(X_5,X_{10})=\sigma^25$, or $corr(X_5,X_{10})=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$

We want to know the distribution U defined as $X_5|{X_{10}=60}$ ; it is Gaussian too (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution) with mean m, and variance $v^2$ such as

$m=45+\frac{\sigma\sqrt{5}}{\sigma\sqrt{10}}\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}(60-50)$

$v^2=(1-{\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}^2)\sigma^25$

Finally ,

$P(X(5)\in (40, 60)\ |\ X(0)=40, X(10) = 60)=P(U\leq60)-P(U\leq40)$

or

$P(m+vY\leq60)-P(m+vY\leq40)=\phi(\frac{60-m}{v})-\phi(\frac{40-m}{v})$

with Y normally distributed mean 0, variance 1

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Could you show me where you get the formula for $m$ and $v^2$, as I could not find it in the Wiki link? In my 2nd solution (shown in the comment section of the OP), I got different means and variance but that's because I compute them for $Y(t) = X(t)-40$. I could not see why we got different means and variance.

Comment: It is in my wikipedia link, look at the section Conditional distributions-Bivariate case

Comment: Thanks so much (I'm blind:p). Btw, the reason you could drop the condition $X(0)=40$ is due to a property of Brownian motion, correct?

Comment: Yeah , it is the initial condition and it brings no randomness.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. Just to make sure my understanding is correct: if we are given only $X(0)=40$, then we could conclude that the probability distribution of $X(5)$ follows $N(45, 5\sigma^2)$?

Comment: I am sorry, but how did you get $cov(X(5), X(10)) = E(X(5)X(10)) - E(X(5))E(X(10)) = 5\sigma^2$? Also, if your calculation is correct, the correlation coefficient cannot be $\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}}$. It should be $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{10}}$. Could you elaborate on your calculation?

Comment: $cov(X_5,X_{10})=cov(\sigma W_5,\sigma W_{10})=\sigma^2cov(W_5,W_{10})=\sigma^2min(5,10)$

$corr(X_5,X_{10})=\frac{cov(X_5,X_{10})}{\sqrt{var(X_5)}\sqrt{var(X_10)}}=\frac{5\sigma^2}{\sqrt{5\sigma^2}\sqrt{10\sigma^2}}$

Comment: I have another question: For the question above, if I want to compute $P(X(5)>10| X(0)=20)$, it would be equivalent to computing $P(X(5)>10-20 =-10)$, correct?